# Step through image pixels to get values

Tags: java, image-processing

So I am looking to calculate the values of each pixel in an image. I will read in an image and then i need to split this image into a number of windows and then move through each pixel within each window and calculate the value of these pixels.

Is there any ideas on how i would go about this or any useful links you think may help.

I have the following outline of pseudo code if this makes it clearer

```
Int w=8;
Int n=256;
Int nblock=n/w;
Double s=0;
For (int i=0;i<nblock;i++) {
    For (int j=0;j<nblock;j++) {
        // put the gray value of the content of the block (i,j) into an array for both images (one array per image)
        // compute the mean, sd, covariance for the arrays you got
        // use the equation of the structural similarity measure to get a value v en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity
        s+=v;
    }
}
v=v/(nblock*nblock)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to split an image into pieces, how to create windows, how to retrieve pixel values? Or do you want the complete program?

Comment: No just to be able to split an image into different windows and retrieve pixel values from each window

Comment: I have the following outline of pseudo code if this makes it clearer                                                             Int w=8;
Int n=256;
Int nblock=n/w;
Double s=0;
For (int i=0;i<nblock;i++)
For (int j=0;j<nblock;j++)
{
       // put the gray value of the content of the block (i,j) into an array for both images (one array per image)
 
      // compute the mean, sd, covariance for the arrays you got
 
    // use the equation of the structural similarity measure to get a value v
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity
 
s+=v;
}
v=v/(nblock*nblock);

Comment: @NiamhMc please edit your question to add significant updates (e.g. code snippets)

Comment: I just put your pseudo code from your comment into your question. I also added a closing brace for one of the for loops. Please click on "edit" to see how this looks when typing it up.

Comment: You are welcome. You have a good start, why don't you continue developing your code? First try starting off with a couple of dummy arrays to represent your image data. Once you get it working with your dummy arrays, then  add in your image reading code.